# How to expose a version in a go cli app when the git-tag is created from a pipeline (but the go app would this information earlier)

Tags: go, deployment, continuous-integration, release

I started developing an app that validates semantic versions in Go because I need this feature and because I want to learn about TDD with Go. I use Cobra as CLI library.

I would like to expose the current version of my app with the default `-h` flag. But I'm not sure how to do this. The go code is not that difficult. Cobra provides an option tp expose the option. I could hardcode the version or read it from a file or something.

```golang
cmd := &cobra.Command{
    Use:     "semver",
    Version: "Lorem ...",                   // TODO ... ... ...
    Short:   "Root: Lorem ipsum ...",       // TODO ... ... ...
    Long:    "Root: Lorem ipsum dolor ...", // TODO ... ... ...
    Args:    cobra.ExactArgs(0),
}

return cmd
```

But here is my problem:

I only build my docker image once because I want to release exactly the image I tested. I build a potentially unstable image with each push to `main` branch and publish this image with the `:ci` tag to DockerHub. Then I run several tests with this image. When all tests pass, this image is in a releasable state (= no longer unstable) and I can publish a stable release anytime I want. When I publish a release I re-tag the `:ci` image as `:latest` and with the respective version (e.g. `v0.1.0`).

This is why it is tricky, to hardcode the version in my go app or read the version from a file. Because the content of the version-file is not updated when I re-tag the image. So my release `0.1.0` would still carry the `0.1.0-SNAPSHOT` version or the branchname or whatever version I put there.

In other words: I would create an image with a string representing an in-dev state and tag the `:ci` image with this unstable version. When I trigger my Release workflow, I re-tag the image with a version, that is createn during this workflow run (the git tag is created here as well). So the docker image tag is the correct version, but the `-h` cli option does not return this version but still states the old unstable version information.

Anyone got an I idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do what you want without using environment variables or build args. If you are just re-tagging the `:ci` to `:v0.1.0`, the images under the hood will be similar, only tag will differ. And it's impossible to retrieve the tag from inside the container. Are you able to change your re-tag pipeline by any chance?

Comment: I was afraid that this would not be possible ... but before I tinker with my pipeline I will ditch the version-output. The build-once pattern is too important to me. I guess I will switch to another identifier for the version like the git commit sha. This is unique and should be available when building the image.